# How to login to server using private key?

Tags: putty

I have a private key provided to login to the server.

I have convert the private key to the ppk format using puttygen. But, when I tried to login, poup says disconnected: No supported authentication methods available(server sent:public key,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic) appear. why I cannot proceed the process?

Comment: you wrote " poup says disconnected" Do you mean putty says disconnected?

Comment: Are you sure the public key is loaded and it's the correct one from the keypair that will match? You say you converted the private key so did that conversion mean you also need to do something with the public key and then load that back onto the server you are connecting with the key pair authentication? Check that the keypair for what you are using for the authentication is correct.

Comment: yes, putty disconnected. i received the private key from admin and using it, so i thought the public key had been inserted by the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you need to load your ppk into pageant (this is your private key). You may have to type your pass phrase to unlock it into pageant.

Second, you need your public key uploaded to the remote server, for the unix account you'll be using. You should ask an admin to do it for you.

Then, you should be able to login through ssh without entering a password for this unix account.

Comment: i have done the pageant part. but for the public key i had to ask the admin. right now, still cannot access

Comment: To Strangelovian,  I think I once saw a case where a server admin sent out a private key , as its public pair was already uploaded. The OP mentioned that he has a private key from the admin so maybe it's a case like that?

Comment: do i need to alter the key as 1 line? as i search from google, it is the formatting of the private key. if yes, how can i edit it?